# fullcalendar date at bottom of day cell

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

Am using fullCalendar.io 3, and i want to show the date (7,8,10) in each day cell at the bottom instead of top.

I have tried to apply styles to bring them to bottom, they are td's in a thead of table with cls skeleton-content.

Nothing worked, looks like i have to make source code changes. I could get the file where i have to make changes, but it is right approach AFAIK.

There should be some extension or overriding mechanism to acheive this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWdMD.png)

Comment: please show what you tried? Maybe it's nearly right and we can just fix it a little bit.

Comment: Thanks Adyson, i was able to solve this with the below css.
a.fc-day-number {
    width: 18px;
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve this with the help of the following CSS. Margin and top may vary in others cases.

```
a.fc-day-number 
{
  width: 18px;
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```